# How to extract only hours and mins from time

Tags: excel, vba

I have cell value of time with hours and mins. I only need to compare the hours and min with time now to execute a condition.

The code below converting the time value and it is returning the negative value for the PM and gives error. if i don't extract the time it compares the hours mins and secs which automatically becomes false if time is 00:00:01.

Any suggestions

```
Sub country_despatch(ByVal StartRow As Long)
    Dim MyTime As Double
    Dim MyDate As Date

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = StartRow To LastRow
        MyDate = Sheet1.Cells(iRow, "B").Value 'value into date format
        MyTime = CDbl(MyDate) - CLng(MyDate) 'extract only the time from a date/time
        Call display(MyTime, iRow)
        Debug.Print "date", MyDate, CDbl(MyDate)
        Debug.Print "time part", MyTime
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

The expected results to compare only hours and mins with time now hours and mins and return true or false

Answer (score 0):

Think about what your code is doing.  The usual way of extracting time from date in Excel is `=Value - INT(Value)`.  Instead of `INT` you are using `Clng' [which rounds up the input number][1] instead of [returning its integer value][2].  By substituting`CLng`for`INT` you have completely changed how your code calculates time:

Constrast

```
MyTime = CDbl(a) - Int(a)
```

with

```
MyTime = CDbl(a) - CLng(a)
```

using am and pm times.